# Missing select box on sonata_type_model

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I'm getting no rendering for the select box, when using this code:

$formMapper->add('studycourses', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true);

This is what appears:

[image]

But when I do the same with `'expanded' => true` I get the correct result:

[image]

I'm using Sonata Admin Bundle 2.2 and Symfony 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen Sonata Admin so support non expanded multiselect model field. However, I was able to achieve the same result using Select2 tag-like selecting behavior ([Select2 implementing bundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)) or using [drop-down multiselect widget](https://github.com/rc2c/Rc2cFormTwitterBundle).

Comment: If I'd use Select2, I'd have to create a new type to still be able to use the 'Add new' button, or do you know an easier way?

Comment: My issue with that is, that I do not know how to use two fields for one attribute, so that I don't have to write my own 'Add new' functionality.

Comment: I believe, that is achieved by creating a new Form type that includes these two new Forms by `$builder->add(...)` two times. Even through, I do not know, if there exists such Form type that has only the 'Add new' button.

Comment: Unfortunately the second add overrides the first.

Comment: You have to create a new Form and embed 2 Form fields to it. Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994604/error-when-trying-to-use-embedded-forms-in-symfony2